# If ++ (pre/post) have higher precedence, why && is being evaluated first?

Tags: c

Here's my program:

```
 int main(void)
 {
  int i, j, k, m;
  i=-3, j=2, k=0;
  m = k++ && ++i && ++j;
  printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
 return 0;
 }
```

The output of the program above is:

```
 -3 2 1 0
```

But according to operator precedence table, ++ should have evaluated first I guess.
I also tried putting parenthesis around them, but still the output remains same.
I read somewhere that putting parenthesis around will make it evaluate first, no matter what.

Somebody, please make it clear, how it's evaluated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [Behaviour of && in C programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229657/behaviour-of-in-c-programming-language/18229763#18229763)

Comment: What you are trying to do? What is 'm'?

Comment: because `k = 0` so expression `k++ && ++i && ++j;` equivalent to `0 && ++i && ++j;`, `k++;` and `0 && ++i && ++j;` = `False` so `++j` and `k++` will not be evaluated .

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980757/arithmetic-c-operators/).

Comment: Precedence doesn't have anything to do with execution order; it only affects how operator arguments are grouped.

Comment: Neither precedence nor parenthesis have anything to do with order of evaluation. Order of evaluation is defined (when it is defined) by sequencing, which is a completely different concept. Sequencing (or its absence) is an inherent property of operators, which cannot be changed by any parenthesis.

Comment: Yeah, I already know that.
I mean, for example, if I write
    x=0;
    a= x + (x=4);
Output will be
    a = 4 + 4 = 8
If I am not wrong.

The expression inside parenthesis is evaluated first.
So, why not in my program above?

Comment: @1lastBr3ath: No. In `a = x + (x=4)` the expression inside the `()` is not "evaluated first". In fact, `a = x + (x=4)` produces *undefined behavior* specifically because of sequencing problems present in that expression. It is not `a = 4 + 4` as you incorrectly believe. It is impossible to predict what will happen to `a` in `a = x + (x=4)`. It can be evaluated as `a = 0 + 4` or as `a = 4 + 4` or as `a = 253 + 128` or it can simply crash. The behavior is, again, undefined.

Comment: Okay.
So, operator precedence just groups operands together, right?
Evaluation of operands is not defined, except in cases of &&, ||, ?:, and comma operator which introduces sequence points, right?
One more question, what is unspecified.
I don't think it's undefined, and what is implementation defined?

Comment: @1lastBr3ath: That's correct. As for different kinds of behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing **precedence** with **order of evaluation**. Precedence defined how the operands are grouped. The higher precedence of `++` makes the expression equivalent to:

```
m = (k++) && (++i) && (++j);
```

But the evaluation order is irrelevant. The shortcut circuit of `&&` guarantees
that its left-hand operand is evaluated first.

In general, most operator doesn't specify the order of evaluation, with four exceptions: logical AND `&&`, logical OR`||`, conditional operator `?:` and comma operator `,`.

---

As a concrete example of different order of evaluation:

Given `int i = 0`, the result of `i + (i++)` is unspecified, the compiler may evaluates `i++` first, which modifies the value of `i`, the compiler may choose to evaluates `i` first. You should avoid expressions like these.

On the other hand, the result of `i && (i++)` is determined, as `&&` ensures the left operand `i` is evaluated first, since it's zero, the right operand `i++` is never evaluated.

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact difference with example?
I always thoughto perators with higher precedence evaluate first :(

Comment: @1lastBr3ath I added an example, hope that's more clear to you.

Comment: Is this also undefined?

int main(void)
{
int x, y, z;
x = y + z + 10 == (y = z =  0);
printf("x = %d, y = %d, z = %d", x, y, z);
return 0;
}

Comment: @1lastBr3ath Possible using uninitialized variables, yes, it's undefined.

Comment: int main()
{
int x = 2, y = 0;
int z = (y++) ? 2 : y == 1 && x;
printf("%d\n", z);
return 0;
}

why is this program printing 1?
Everything is defined here, I think.

Comment: @1lastBr3ath `y++` is evaluated first, result is `0` then `y` increments to `1`, then `z` takes the value of `y == 1 && x`, since `1 && x` is `1`, so `y == 1` is true, `z` is assigned `1`.

Comment: Conditional operator operates from right-to-left, doesn't it?
while && guarentees left-to-right operation, right?
So, it should have evaluated as:

z = (y++) ? (2) : ((y==1) && x)

Where operating from right-to-left, ((y==1) && x) should be evaluated first, if I'm not wrong.
Conditional operator also introduces a sequence point, doesn't it?
Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: @1lastBr3ath No, the conditional operator evaluates its first operand first, and then evaluates its second or third operand depending on if the fist value is non-zero or zero. Did you take the idea of `?:` operates from right to left because it's **right associate** ?

Comment: Yup.
So, what does it mean by "right associativity"?

Comment: @1lastBr3ath It's too big a topic to discuss in the comment. Basically, **precedence** decides the grouping of different operators, right? But actually some operators have the same precedence, e.g, binary `+` and `-`, **associativity** decides the grouping of operators with the same precedence. `1+2-3` is grouped as `(1+2)-3`, right? that's because`+` `-` are left associate.

Answer (score 4):

What's happening here is short-circuiting. `k++` evaluates to `0`, which is false. Thus the entire boolean expression `k++ && ++i && ++j` is false, so `++i` and `++j` are never executed.